# Stop UIView from roating into landscape

Tags: ios, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a UIView thats inside a navigation controller, I am trying to prevent this view from going into Landscape however the method I am trying to use never fires.. code is below any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: is that method in a view or a view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `return NO;` for the parent navigation controller or on a `UIViewController`, not a `UIView`.

Also, this works just the same with less code:

### iOS 5.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

### iOS 6

As of iOS 6, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated. If the view controller does not override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method, `UIKit` obtains the default rotations from the app delegate or the app’s Info.plist file.

You will need to use:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Comment: As I remarked in my response, always returning `NO` is considered improper and (last I checked) triggers a run-time warning.

Comment: sorry this is not working for me.. as from another answer I read that its on invoked on a view but on the viewcontroller. I have a UIView in  InterfaceBuilder which is linked to the fileOwner as a view.. but I just dunno what else to look for to get this thing to stop rotating.

Comment: Place this code on your parent `UINavigationController`, as explained, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is apart of the `UIViewController` class and will not work on a `UIView`.

Comment: right.. I understand now.. I should also tell you that I was only wanting to prevent this view from rotating not every view in my NavigationController.. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can set a `BOOL` option to see if the view is visible. If it is, then disable rotation. So when you show the view, set something like `myViewIsShowing = YES;`. `if (myViewIsShowing) /*do not rotate */;`

Comment: Okay I'm having difficulty here :( I know that you want me to place the code on my parent UINavController, however I am using a master-detail Application, the masterView is simply a UIViewController of a uiview, the NavigationController is declared in the appDelegate.. I'm kinda lost as to where I can put this code to get it to work.. i have tried everywhere and still no success..

Comment: You should probably read the Apple docs on both `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` to get a better understanding.

Comment: Have you used the template "master-detail Application"?

Comment: On many occasions. The template you use makes no difference. The classes still require the same methods.

Comment: humor me, start your own "master-detail Application" thats standard in the apple templates when it loads go to masterViewController.m in there you will see the exact same method you have suggested above, change it from  **!= UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown** to what you have suggested **== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait** then run it on a device and see what happens.. the damn thing is broken.. unless I am going absolutely crazy, I have tried this twice on my project which is very similar to the template just with few alterations and then on a completely fresh template.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax : `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`. Is that really what I have to type ? If it is, it's the 1st time I see that.

Comment: No, NS_AVAIL just tells  you that it's available only in iOS 6. It's from the Apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is modifying Deployment Info.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This method needs to be implemented in a `UIViewController` instance, not a `UIView`.

Also, you are in fact returning `NO` for all orientations, which is incorrect.  You need to return `YES` for at least one orientation (most commonly `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`).

Comment: woopsie!!! i had it at yes at one point and in my frantic state of trying to find a solution must have changed that for some weird reason.