# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not working in iOS 6

Tags: xcode, orientation, ios6, screen-orientation

In iOS 6, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not working, but it worked fine in iOS 5.0 and 5.1.

What do I need to change for iOS 6? Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if([[[SampleApplicationAppDelegate instance].callInfoDictionary valueForKey:IS_CHAT] isEqualToString:NO_RESPONSE])
{
    int nAngle = 0;
    BOOL bRet = NO;
    
    switch (interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            nAngle = 90;
            bRet = YES;
            NSLog(@".......Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);
            
            _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
            
            NSLog(@"Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);
            break;
            
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            nAngle = 270;
            bRet = YES;
            _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;
            
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            nAngle = 0;
            bRet = YES;
            //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
            break;
            
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            nAngle = 180;
            bRet = YES;
            //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }                
    return bRet;
}    
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    return YES;     
return NO;    
}
```

When I searched for this orientation problem, all I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441762/stop-uiview-from-roating-into-landscape) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6), but nothing worked for me :(

Please help .....

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is happening because Apple has changed the way of managing the Orientation of `UIViewController`. In iOS6 orientation handles differently. In **iOS6** `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method is deprecated. View controllers (such as `UINavigationController`) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` for the iPad [idiom](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM) and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown` for the iPhone idiom.

If you want a specific view to be changed to the desired orientation you have to do some sort of subclass or category and override the autorotation methods to return the desired orientation.

Place this code in your root view controller. This will help the `UIViewController` to determine its orientation.

```
  //RotationIn_IOS6 is a Category for overriding the default orientation.

  @implementation UINavigationController (RotationIn_IOS6)

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
      return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
    }

  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
     return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
   }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
 {
     return [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
 }

 @end
```

Now you need to implement below methods (introduced in iOS6) in viewController for orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return TRUE;


}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{   
     //decide number of origination tob supported by Viewcontroller.
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
     //from here you Should try to Preferred orientation for ViewController 
   }
```

And put your code inside the below method. Whenever device orientation is changed 
this method will be called:

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if([[[SampleApplicationAppDelegate instance].callInfoDictionary valueForKey:IS_CHAT] isEqualToString:NO_RESPONSE])
{
    int nAngle = 0;
    BOOL bRet = NO;

    switch (interfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            nAngle = 90;
            bRet = YES;
            NSLog(@".......Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);

            _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);

            NSLog(@"Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            nAngle = 270;
            bRet = YES;
            _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            nAngle = 0;
            bRet = YES;
            //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            nAngle = 180;
            bRet = YES;
            //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }                
  }
```

**Edit:** check your window, you need to add the controller on window as `rootViewController` rather than `addSubview` like below

```
self.window.rootViewController=viewController;
```

For more information [here](http://9to5mac.com/2012/06/25/apple-pushes-ios-6-0-update-to-devs/)'s an article about iOS6.0 Beta 2 OTA.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks mate! Great category! Simple but useful :)

Comment: please keep in mind that this is a hackish solution - overriding methods by using category is strongly discouraged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c

Comment: Yours is the _only_ answer I've seen that mentions the crucial delegate method: "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation".  This allows individual viewControllers to do specific things with the change in orientation—just like "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" _used_ to do.  What was served by changing this, Apple?

Comment: `[self.viewControllers lastObject]` is the same as `self.topViewController`

Comment: Jeez, nothing like depreciating a single 2 line method to replace it with several methods adding up to about 100 lines...

Answer (score 15):

The way I fixed this problem was to replace the following line when my app starts in Delegate Class

```
 window addSubview: navigationController.view
```

with

```
window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

After I made this change my app started to handle screen rotations

Comment: By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom. so thats work only specific orientation , if you want to allow all orientation for iphone you'll have allow as i have done in my answer.

Comment: I also used this by setting rootViewController instead of adding subview on that thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Apple has deprecated shouldautorate method from ios6 use these methods instead

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
// Returns interface orientation masks.
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem just use this

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {    
    if(![AppDelegate instance])
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    if([[[AppDelegate instance].callInfoDictionary valueForKey:IS_CHAT] isEqualToString:NO_RESPONSE])
    {
        int nAngle = 0;
        BOOL bRet = NO;

        switch (interfaceOrientation) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            {
                nAngle = 90;
                bRet = YES;
                NSLog(@".......Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);

                NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"6.0" options: NSNumericSearch];
                if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending)
                {
                    // OS version >= 6.0
                    NSLog(@"ami iOS 6 er device");
                    _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                }
                else
                {
                    // OS version < 6.0
                    _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
                }

                NSLog(@"Preview = %f %f",_previewCamera.frame.size.width,_previewCamera.frame.size.height);
                NSLog(@"-->%s %d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
                break;
            }

            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            {

                nAngle = 270;
                bRet = YES;
                NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"6.0" options: NSNumericSearch];
                if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending)
                {
                    // OS version >= 6.0
                    NSLog(@"ami iOS 6 er device");
                    _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
                }
                else
                {
                    // OS version < 6.0
                    _previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                }
                break;
            }
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                nAngle = 0;
                bRet = YES;
                //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*1.5);
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                nAngle = 180;
                bRet = YES;
                //_previewCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }        

        return bRet;
    }   
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        return YES; 
    return NO;    
}
```

Comment: for your kind information i would like to tell this method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` has deprecated in iOS6. it means,in future that method can be remove form iOS SDK. So be careful.

Comment: Yes. You are right.This method will deprecated in iOS6 in near future & i am searching for a better solution.

Comment: have a look of my answer dude.please let me know if you have any issue in my answer

Answer (score 0):

please try this one it will be helpful for you.

write code in you viewcontroller class

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
      return YES;
   }

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
```

Then in appdelegate search this line [window addSubview:viewController.view]
and replace this with window.rootViewController = viewController;

cheers it will work.its simple solution for ios 6

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}


    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            // your code for portrait mode

        }

        return YES;
    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
```