# iphone how to change landscape to portrait?

Tags: iphone

I develop a simple game in iPhone. The whole game is in landscape mode, but the scoreboard page  only support portrait mode. I have checked the questions here, I only find turn portrait into landscape mode, but I need the opposite answer. Could anyone help me?

Comment: here is same thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6/12581799#12581799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple.  First, make sure both portrait and landscape orientations are supported in the target summary.  Then:

In the landscape ViewControllers, add this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

And in the portrait ViewController, add this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these two calls in AppDelegate. Getting game center(score board) in landscape only.

```
// Supported orientations: Landscape. Customize it for your own needs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}



#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown; //Getting error here? then update ur xcode to 4.5+
}
#endif
```

Xcode settings: Mark landscape. [image]

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated as of iOS 6.

Comment: @WolfLink, yes, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is used for ios6 in my code..its working great:) anyway thanks