# iPhone interface orientation change not returning to portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

So I have a view that I present modally when the interface orientation changes to landscape. However when the orientation returns to portrait and the modal view dismisses itself, the tableview from the initial view remains in landscape orientation (this table view must be only in portrait orientation)

Here is the code :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) );
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCatChart" sender:self];
    }
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [self refreshTableView];
    }
}
```

I tried to refresh the tableview but that doesn't make it portrait again ... 
this could be from the view hierachy ... 
NavigationController->tableView (only portrait)->tableview->landscapeViewModalController

Comment: you should take a view of this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6/12581799#12581799

Comment: that is about iOs6 .. I need this t owork on iOs 5/6 iPhone 3gs/4/4s/5 ...

Comment: nothing to worry dude , you should keep the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method in your viewController too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in appdelegate.

```
[self.window addsubview:viewcontroller];
```

This alone will solve your orientation problem.

Comment: And viewController should be what? The initial navigationController?

Comment: Yes,n use that navigationcontroller as     [self.window addsubview:navigationcontroller.view];

Comment: doesn't work ... same problem ... the view returns to portrait mode but the display in it looks like it's in landscape ...

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 6, you need to implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

In your AppDelegate, you need to change the following:

```
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to

```
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Also, keep your current code if you want to support previous versions of iOS.