# iOS6 Device Rotation To Be Restricted

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autorotate

For my app, I want to let the device rotate anyway but upside-down.  This is working fine.  However, I want to stop the app from rotating specifically from

**landscape left -> landscape right** - and vice versa

If anyone is curious, this is because that rotation messes up my layouts, as they each rotate from a common point

My code for iOS 5, which I think would work, is like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    NSLog(@"Rotating");
    if((lastOrient == 3 && toInterfaceOrientation == 4) || (lastOrient == 4 && toInterfaceOrientation == 3)){
       lastOrient = toInterfaceOrientation;
       return NO;
    }

   lastOrient = toInterfaceOrientation;
   return YES;

}
```

Where 3= landscape left and 4= landscape right

Any suggestions on how to do this with iOS6? Or a completely different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I answered my own question here:

The good news is, there is definitely a way to do this!  So heres the basics:

In iOS6, it is up to the appDelegate to handle whether the app can rotate in general.  Then, when the device gets a rotation signal, it will ask your view for its supported orientations.  This is where I implemented my code.  In fact, shouldAutorotate() plays no role in the solution.

So I create a variable to keep track of the last orientation, and change it in

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
```

This way I can compare orientations

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSLog(@"Last Orient = %d", lastOrient);
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    if (lastOrient != 3 && lastOrient != 4) {
        NSLog(@"All good, rotate anywhere");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else if(lastOrient == 3){
        orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
        NSLog(@"Can only rotate right");
    }
    else if(lastOrient == 4){
        orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
        NSLog(@"Can only rotate left");
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

Seems to work for me.  Slightly a hack, but it does what it needs to do

Answer (score 1):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in ios6.  Use this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (lastOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
 return NO;

}

return YES;
}
```

Haven't tested this code.  You can get more info on these posts:
[shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not working in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6)
[shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6)

Comment: apparently you can include both implementations (shouldAutorotateToOrientation and shouldAutorotate) and it should cascade down from ios6