# enable interface orientation on a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not working in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6)

I am using xcode 4.5, I need to enable interface orientation only on one viewController containing a webview in it. How can i enable it.

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` seems deprecated in iOS6

Comment: i have seen this post, using method of this post and below venkatesh i am still not able to rotate

Comment: clean build, and double check .plist settings.

Answer (score 5):

Instead you can use this UIViewController

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
        return YES; //supports all
    }

    -(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown; //supports all but upside-down
}
```

Comment: i do this but it doesnot rotate

Comment: is there any enabling in webview too?

Comment: Are you using any UINavigation Controller or UITabBar Controller in ur app?can u pls tell me.

Comment: both UINavigation in Tabbar

Comment: Then please add your tabbar controller to the window like this "self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;" instead of add subview in ur appdelegate.Hope tabbar is ur topview controller.

Answer (score 1):

This API does not works in iOS 6 anymore. There is no way that you can enable it. See the link shared by @Shivan Raptor