# Landscape fullscreen youtube movie from portrait UIWebView in portrait only app in iOS 4.3, 5.0 and 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube, orientation

I've spent several hours researching this and I'm still confused. It seems to be so common task that I started to think that I missed something simple.

The problem is:

I have a Portrait-only iPhone app. Basically an UINavigationController that presents a modal UIViewController at some point. There is an UIWebView in that modally presented controller which displays youtube video. When user taps on that webView the fullscreen movie player shows up, which is great, but it shows in portrait and there is no way to rotate it. I want it to be able to rotate or at least show full screen already rotated to landscape, with all my other controllers remaining portrait-only.

The only solution I can think of is to do the following:
1. allow the app and all controllers to support portrait and landscape
2. observe orientation changes in all controllers
3. disable UIView animations in willRotate
4. when orientation changes set the view transform to 90deg or -90deg rotation

This seem like a lot of work to achieve simple effect of youtube playing in landscape in portrait-only app! Are there simpler methods?

Comment: Did you get solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and return only YES when the video is playing fullscreen.

Comment: 1. in which controller? all of them? or UINavigationController subclass? or only this modal that is showing a webview? 2. Anyway it won't work for iOS 6 as this method is deprecated.

Comment: Check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6) on how to have fine control on the orientations for each controller. I think the controller you want to rotate is the modal one. If that doesn't work go up in the hierarchy. Because it's an iPhone the modal is fullscreen so it should work on the modal.