# iPad simulator just shows black screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am developing an app in Xcode, I got it working and was putting some finishing touches.
Then I upgraded Xcode to the latest version, changed a bit the code for the Autorotate options (my app shouldn't autorotate) and fiddled with the supported rotation (landscape vs. portait).
Then suddenly my debug in iOs simulator just shows a black screen. The app builds fine but nothing is shown in the simulator....
And I can't really understand why...

Using Xcode 4.6

i don't have an ApplicationDidFinishLoading but I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

[window addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
return YES; }
```

Comment: Any log you can give ? Try removing the app from the simulator, clean the project and re-run.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, somewhere in you're AppDelegate. See how far you come...

Comment: which is the current version of xcode. and can you please provide the Appdidfinishload code here

Comment: Xcode 4.6
i don't have an ApplicationDidFinishLoading but I have this:
<code>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
 
 
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

</code>

Comment: Allocate the ViewController of your root view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below Code instead in your ApplicationDidFinishLoading

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[YourFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This may solve your problem. Please try it.

Comment: thanks now something shows in the interface, even it's in portait mode instead of landscape...

Comment: i set "initial interface orientation" and "supported interface orientation" both to Landscape (right button) but interface it's not correct

Comment: Some of the rotation methods are deprecated such as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation .So pls check weather your functions are get called

Comment: THANKS MELBOURNE. commenting the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" solved my problem. THANKS A MILLION !!!

Comment: It works under Simulator 6.1, but not in Simulator 5.1 and my iPad which has 5.1...how can i make it work under both iOs (5 and 6)???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6 pls refer this one

Answer (score 0):

commenting the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" solved my problem.