# MvvmCross -- MvxViewController, and ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I would like to rotate the orientation of my screen in MvvmCross.  Typically, I would simply override ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, though this method is revealed to be obsolete when overridden while the MvxViewController is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

That method has been deprecated for ios6 and later - see some of the details in questions and links like:

- [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not working in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6)
- http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/where-did-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-go-in-ios-6
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/